# How to update ListFragment whenever data updated in Sqlite Database

Tags: android, android-fragments

How to update ListFragment whenever data updated in Sqlite Database.My following Fragment code works properly,how to update this list fragment?

```
public class MyMasterFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /*
        Runnable mRunnable=new Runnable() {
               public void run() {
                     Log.i("mylog", "refreshing...");
                     ListAdapter myListAdapter = getMyListAdapter();
                     setListAdapter(myListAdapter);
                     Log.i("mylog", "list Updated");
                     mHandler.postDelayed( this, 60*1000 );
                   }
        };

        mHandler.postDelayed( mRunnable, 0);
        */

        ListAdapter myListAdapter = getMyListAdapter();
        setListAdapter(myListAdapter);

    }

    private ListAdapter getMyListAdapter() {
        DBHelper dbHelper=new DBHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase myDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        ListAdapter adapter = null ;
            String TIME_SORT_ORDER=DBConstants.TIME+" DESC";
            String[] mycolumns={DBConstants.SNO,DBConstants.MYSYMBOL,DBConstants.VALUE1,DBConstants.DATE,DBConstants.TIME,DBConstants.VALUE2,DBConstants.VALUE3,DBConstants.VALUE4,DBConstants.VALUE5,DBConstants.VALUE6};
            Cursor c1 = myDB.query(DBConstants.LATEST_MY_DATA_TABLE,mycolumns, null, null, null, null, TIME_SORT_ORDER);

            if(c1.getCount()>0)
            {
                adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.live_list_item, c1, new String[] {DBConstants.MYSYMBOL,DBConstants.VALUE1,DBConstants.VALUE2,DBConstants.DATE,DBConstants.TIME}, new int[] {R.id.mysymbol, R.id.value1,R.id.value2,R.id.ldate,R.id.ltime});
            }
        myDB.close();
        dbHelper.close();
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

Also i have studied about Loader Manager in Android document.

1. If i use loader manager it automatically updates my fragment list whenever data updated in my DB?
2. Can i use Loader manager on Pre-honeycomb versionz using Support Library?

Comment: Depends on who updates data, is it your own App ?

Comment: yes from my own Application sqlite DB

Comment: well, then you can trigger `getLoaderManager.initLoader()` whenever you _finish_ updating data.

Comment: Data updated in DB using Seperate Service.So shall i want init Loader manager inside service after data updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i use loader manager it automatically updates my fragment list
>   whenever data updated in my DB?

Nope, you have to listen to some internal event, or external broadcast to re-run the load.

- Services: When you bind with a service, you share an Interface
  [`IBinder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder.html)
  to communicate. Using that , service can notify your Activity that it
  has updated the DB.

> Can i use Loader manager on Pre-honeycomb versionz using Support
>   Library?

Yes, you can.